# Different output of textview in android os 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

i have build some simple app which contain one textview and two button

and at programmatic i have find there id and change textsize as button click as per below.

```
Button btn1,btn2;
    TextView txtmain;

        txtmain=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        txtmain.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                txtmain.setTextSize(30);
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                txtmain.setTextSize(100);

            }
        });
```

so the output is as below when i click btn2 textsize is 100 and when i select textview size is 30 but in android os 4.0.3 output is very different from other os.

button1 click output screen[image: button1 click and textview size is 30 so output]

button2 click output screen [image: btton2 click and textview size is 100 so output]

Again button1 click mismatch output as per button1 clicked image[image]

so please help me how to solved this problem this is one simple demo. is this any os related problem because apart from android os 4.0.3 it is run perfect.

Comment: hey i have checked in all os the problem is in android os version 4.0.3.

Comment: just reinitialize the LayoutParams of txtmain in onClick of Buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the following link.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17343

this is the android ice cream sandwich issue .

solve this issue add extra spacing character end of the text.

example:

```
final String DOUBLE_BYTE_WORDJOINER = "\u2060";
txtmain=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txtmain.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP ,30);
txtmain.append(DOUBLE_BYTE_WORDJOINER);
```